# Riemannian metrics on matrix space for which the restriction of trace function to each complete geodesic is a bounded function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, matrix-analysis, geodesics

**Edit:** According to comment   by Leo Monsaingeon I revise my question:

Is there a Riemannian metric on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ for which the function $trace$ is a  bounded   function on **every complete(whole)** geodesic? that is  for  every **complete** geodesic $\gamma$, the restriction $trace$ to $\gamma$ is a bounded function? What about the same question if we replace $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

**Remark** By a   complete  geodesic  we  DO NOT  mean exclusively a  geodesic whose parameter $t$ can be varied in whole  $\mathbb{R}$, but we mean $\{\gamma(t)\mid t\in I\}$ where $I$ is the maximal interval of  definition of $\gamma$. So we mean the  whole trajectory of a non parametrized geodesic.

Comment: Do you mean complete geodesics? Or just two-points geodesics between arbitrary matrices $M,N$? In the latter case the Hilbert structure induced by the Frobenius scalar product should do, right?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon  I think it is the Eucliean metric so the geodesic $\begin{pmatrix}t&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ has an unbounded trace, right?

Comment: well, not if you mean "geodesics between arbitrary pairs of points", in which case your time parameter cannot run across the whole real line. But I guess from your comment that you really mean "complete geodesics", right? If so perhaps it would be worth editing your question (also, there is a typo in your title "o"->"of")

Comment: @leomonsaingeon  I mean complete geodesic, otherwise not only trace but also every continuous function on a compact set9geoesic from M to N) is a bounded function

Comment: right, but the continuity of the trace function depends on the choice of the metric (although I agree that pretty much all the Riemannian structures should give an equivalent topology). So it was not completely clear for me what you meant. Now it is ;-)

Comment: @leomonsaingeon  Thank you for  your comment. I revise my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to find such metrics. However,  they are a bit unnatural, in that they aren't really constructed from any inherent properties of matrices. For concreteness, I'm going to restrict my attention to $M_2$ and $Gl_2$, but this construction can be modified to work for any larger $n$ as well.

We consider $2 \times 2$ matrices $$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 a  & b \\
 c &  d \\
\end{array}
\right]. $$

To construct the desired metric, we start by changing coordinates on $M_2$ as follows.

$x = a+d$, $y= \exp(a-d)$, $z=b$, $w=c$

This gives a map from $M_2$ to a half-space in $\mathbb{R}^4$. For a Riemannian metric, we use $$ds^2 = \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2} +dz^2+dw^2.$$

Notice that the $x$-coordinate is simply the trace of the original matrix, so what's left to show is that $x$ is bounded on any geodesic. Different geodesics will have different bounds, however.

To show that $x$ is bounded on any geodesic, observe that as a Riemannian manifold, $(M_n, g)$ is simply the metric product $\mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{R}^2$. As such,  the geodesics are of the form  $\gamma(t) = (c(t), \ell(t))$. 
Here, $c(t)$ forms an arc of a semi-circle in $\mathbb{H} $ whose center is on the axis $y=0$. Meanwhile, $\ell(t))$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As such, it follows the $x$ coordinate is bounded by the center and radius of $c(t)$.

When we try to do this for $Gl_2$, we have to deal with the fact that the space is disconnected. However, we can use a similar idea on each connected component. Namely, we change coordinates to
$x = a+d$, $y= \exp(a-d)$, $z=b$, $w=ad-bc$ and take the metric 
$ds^2 = \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2} +\frac{dz^2+dw^2}{w^2}.$
This gives $Gl_2$ the metric structure of $\mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{H}$ on each of its connected components, which also has the desired geodesic property.